# how make to realtime update in div content using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

so i'm working on my project and i want to do is Real time fetch from my database and display it in my div real time (which is the 3 trash bins) using j-query ajax can someone help me with this

iv'e done using pure ajax and i want to apply it using j-query someone help me with this one please

```js
function binload() {

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("GET", "tank.php", true);
    ajax.onload = function(){
            document.getElementById("water1").style.height = ajax.responseText;
            document.getElementById("water2").style.height = ajax.responseText;
            document.getElementById("water3").style.height = ajax.responseText;   
    }
    ajax.send();
    
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(data);
            
            var html = "";
            for(var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
                var ID = data[a].ID;
                var Bio = data[a].Bio;
                var Non_Bio = data[a].Non_Bio;
                var Recy = data[a].Recy;
                var Extra = data[a].Extra;

               
            }
            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML += html; 

            var obtained = Bio;  
            var obtained2 = Non_Bio;
            var obtained3 = Recy;
            var div = 5000;

            var obt = obtained*100/div;
            var obt2 = obtained2*100/div;
            var obt3 = obtained3*100/div;

            console.log(obt);
            console.log(obt2);
            console.log(obt3);

            document.getElementById("water1").style.height = obt + "%";
            document.getElementById("water2").style.height = obt2 + "%";
            document.getElementById("water3").style.height = obt3 + "%";
        
        }       
    };
}
```

```css
.tank {
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}

.tank .water {
    position: absolute;
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body onload="binload()">

<div class="tank">
    <div class="water" id="water1" ></div>
</div>

<div class="tank">
    <div class="water" id="water2"></div>
</div>

<div class="tank">
    <div class="water" id="water3"></div>
</div>
```

here is my php code

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "trashbin");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM trash");

$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
{
    array_push($data, $row);
}

echo json_encode($data);
exit();
```

can someone help me with this one thanks a lot :)

Comment: does it show any error?

Comment: no error but i just want to convert it to jquery coz im targeting 2 platforms on my project which is web and mobile (android) but im not familiar with jquery help me with this one pls thanks

Comment: when will the function `binload` will be called or loaded?

Comment: currently when the body loads but i figured out i want to do is realtime maybe it will load every second so that its just like realtime is that possible with jquery?

Comment: You can use what you have without needing jquery. Just need an interval timer

Comment: how about when i use jquery coz i like to convert my plain javascript to jquery can you help me with that?

Comment: Unfortunately Stackoverflow is not a free code conversion service

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with plain javascript . like this

```
setInterval(binload,1000);
```

It will call the function after every 1 second.